# Compiling error c#

Tags: c#

I have a amount of code that compiles in visual studio, however in a different ide it doesn't compile.

the error that is returned is System.IO file does not contain a defintion for "ReadLines".

i am using system.io

the section of the code that appears with an eror is ReadLines.

could anybody offer a soultion?

```
using System;
using System.IO;                      // enable the user of different sections of the .net framework 
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace HashTagAssignment
{
    class HashTag
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tweets = File.ReadAllText(@"F:\tweets.txt"); // Retrives Text from file and loads into console
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tweets); // writes contense to console
                {
                    var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\tweets.txt").Length; // counts number of lines in the whole document
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of Lines:{0}", lineCount); // displays answer
                    {
                        var result = File.ReadLines(@"F:\tweets.txt").Distinct().Count(); // search txt file for Distinct enteries and implement counter. 
                        Console.WriteLine(" Number of Unique Tags: {0}", result); // display result of counter 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" Top Twenty By Number:"); // Title Top twenty hash tags, with order they occured in left colum. 
                            Console.WriteLine(); // creates a line space 
                            var rank = File // assigns varible to a file 
                        .ReadLines(@"F:\tweets.txt") // directs to file, in this case text
                      .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Count)
    .Take(20);
                            foreach (var item in rank)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Count, item.Key);
                            }
                            {
                                {
                                }
                                Console.ReadKey(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's see the code and the error?

Comment: Are we meant to guess the other IDE? Perhaps you tried to compile you C# program in Netbeans.

Comment: Please learn how to format code

Comment: Are you looking for `File.ReadLines`?  Can you post the code?

Comment: Why are you creating a new scope block after almost every `Console.WriteLine()` call?

Comment: Do you realize you're reading the same file 4 times?

Answer (score 10):

The `File.ReadLines` method is new to .Net 4.0.

Comment: is they're an alternative i can use for 3.5 and under?

Comment: the compiler im using is sharpdevelop

Comment: @Evildommer5 You can use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=VS.80).aspx) instead (.NET 2.0+), but this won't lazily enumerate like `ReadLines` does.

Comment: What version of SharpDevelop?  According to the site, 4.1 will support targeting the .NET 4 framework.

Comment: Oh... You gave up your mod powers?

Answer (score 1):

File.ReadLines is not available before .NET 4.0. You need to make sure you are compiling for .NET 4.0+, or a compatible version of Mono.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only getting this error in a different IDE make sure your solution/project (if the other IDE even uses it) has a reference to the assembly that contains it. Which I think is  mscorlib.dll.

EDIT: just curious, what IDE?

Comment: Does SharpDevelop not support .NET 4?  Why switch from VS?

Comment: Because i need to make sure it compiles on computers that i dont have vs on

Comment: The computer only needs the .NET 4 runtime to run your program, not Visual Studio.